# How to extract part of recorded audio bytes

Tags: java, android, audio, record, android-mediarecorder

I recording sound to byte array, see below:

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(1024*1024);
```

...

```
    while (hasRecording) {
        try {
            int read = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length);
            if (read == -1)
                break;

            byteArrayOutputStream.write(data, 0, read);
            byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

By recording I am drawing amplitude to chart (on the fly). After stop recording user can select part of chart. And now, how can I extract part of byte array by the user selection? I have only position selected coords and byte array of completed recorded sound.
I know, that I have to calculate with bitrate for gets position in byte array, but I don't know how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to determine the number of bytes per frame? I can see that you have 44100 frames per second. But I don't usually work with audio in terms of bit rates and am not clear what that relates to.

In a pure Java context, the `AudioFormat` is defined in terms of the bits used for encoding, with 16 bits (two bytes) being the most common, and the number of channels, e.g., 1 channel for mono, 2 channels for stereo.

With what is known as the common "CD Quality" format, we have 16-bit encoding and stereo, thus 4 bytes per frame. From that and the frame rate, it is a simple matter to correlate a specific byte to a moment in time.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can determine number of bytes per frame. I will try it by your description.

Comment: I'am encoding AMR bit rate 12.2kb/s ~ 32bytes frame size. How can I used it?

Comment: I'd try assuming stereo with 16 bits encoding. This seems most likely. At 44100 bytes per second, that comes to a ratio of 1378.125 frames per second. (44100 / 32). You can use this ratio to align your timing axis to the PCM data. Audio data should alternate 16 bits Left, 16 bits Right for each frame. IDK how you plan to handle the stereo aspect, but this should give you what you need to find the time value that corresponds to a specific frame.

Answer (score 0):

If the array has size N and contains T seconds of audio data (from t=0 to t=T), then the data at time t will be at index t*N/T.

Comment: Sorry, but array isn't consist of one byte per second. One second is more bytes.

Comment: "array isn't consist of one byte per second": did I say that somewhere?

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding. Can you more explain it, your idea with formula? Do you mean, every seconds has same count of bytes? If true, than formula maybe working. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. If I gets part of array then listening sound is distorted.